# Item "prototype" for "Array" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, collections

im working with Symfony2 and mopaboostraps. I want to make a e-mail-collection element in my form and everything worked well till today (i rly dont knwo why)

i get the following error:

```
Item "prototype" for "Array" does not exist in *snip*.html.twig at line 36
```

which is this:

```
<span id="member-fields-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.members.vars.prototype)|e }}"></span>
```

i searched a while and found only one hint: my collection elment is null (it will be filled via javascript) but if i add a value to it it'll work neither

```
$UserList = new UserList();
        **********snip***********
        $UserList->setMembers(array());

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($UserList)
        **********snip***********
    ->add('members', 'collection', array(   
                'type' => 'email',
                'prototype' => true,
                // 'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'email-box',
                        'readonly' => 'readonly',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
```

## edit: got the solution

just uncomment 'allow_add' XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncomment 'allow_add' solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

form_widget is used to get just one widget of the collection (understand "one sub field"), and form_row is to get the full prototype (all sub fields of a member in your example).

So use [form_row](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/collection.html#prototype) instead to display the full prototype of a member:

```
{{ form_row(form.members.vars.prototype)|e }}
```

Use form_widget only to get one field of a member, for example "username":

```
{{ form_widget(form.members.vars.prototype.username)|e }}
```

You can also get individually the form_error of just one field and its label:

```
{{ form_errors(form.members.vars.prototype.username)|e  }}
{{ form_label(form.members.vars.prototype.username, 'My label')|e  }}
```

Comment: i get the same error with form_row ... but am i right:
prototype is exactly one sub field of "members" and there is only 1 prototype for all my "members" fields
??